# I2C data receiving method

Tags: ros2, arduino

I am planning to use arduino.

Here, we confirmed that data from products used as I2C can be received via USB or serial.

Now I want to see the data structure in order to read it like pl2303 and use it as a message.

In other words, is it possible that data is received through serial communication without USB(Only use pin). - (Just connect Rx -Tx ?)

What should I refer to in order to receive this from a pin rather than USB?

Question2. This does not yet have a data structure. What should I consider adding to update the messages (QOS) that ros2 can receive?